# Format column with prefixes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to format my "VOLUME" column the same way like the "MKT CAP" column with prefixes.
Prefixes like "M" for 10^6 or "k" for 10^3
I used the numerize library for this but need help to make it work for formatting the whole VOLUME column.

```
import pandas as pd
from numerize import numerize  
      
df = pd.read_html('https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-pre-market-gainers')[0]
df.columns =['TICKER', 'CLOSE', 'PRE-MKT CHG', 'CHG %', 'VOLUME', 'PRE-MKT GAP %', 'PRICE', 'CHG1 %', 'VOL', 'MKT CAP']
df = df.reindex(columns=['TICKER', 'CHG %', 'VOLUME', 'MKT CAP', 'CLOSE'])
df['VOLUME'] =df[numerize.numerize(df['VOLUME'])] #this line did not work
```

Also how can i filter out the first letter and space for only the yellow marked cells?
There needs to be a filter looking for a space and also remove the first letter.

[image: Table looks like this]

Comment: You've asked two questions here - best to ask separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace and first character can be filtered out by following line.

```
df['TICKER'] = df['TICKER'].str.replace('^.\s\s', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

For your numerize function try:

```py
df['VOLUME'] = df['VOLUME'].apply(numerize.numerize)
```

For the string column, you can match using regex `^.\s` to capture any single character followed by a space:

```py
df['TICKER'] = df['TICKER'].str.replace('^.\s', '', regex=True)
```

If you have multiple whitespace characters after the first character you can do:

```py
df['TICKER'] = df['TICKER'].str.replace('^.\s{1,}', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: The numerize code line works fine. Thanks.
Regarding the regex. The first letter is filtered out but the space is still unfiltered.

Comment: You must have whitespace characters if your filter works - you can use `^.\s{1,}` to match one or more whitespace characters after the first character.